# Is there a numpy magic avoiding these loops?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I would like to avoid `for` loops in this code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

N = 4
a = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(N, N, 3))
m = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(N, N))

for i, d0 in enumerate(a):
  for j, d1 in enumerate(d0):
    if m[i, j]:
      d1[2] = 42
```

This is a simplified example where `a` is an N x N RGB image and `m` is a N x N mask, which sets masked elements of the 3rd channel: `a[:, :, 2]` only.

Comment: Do you want to avoid `for` loops for aesthetics or do you need performance gains?

Comment: @vaizki Performance and aesthetics, if possible.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Nice. Transpose is not needed: `a[...,2][m.astype('bool')] = 42`

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Post it and I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: @PaulJurczak - I always get confused when the channels are in the last axis. Not your fault, I know there are libraries that prefer this structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can index the last axis and set the elements selected by a boolean mask

```
import numpy as np

N = 4
a = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(N, N, 3))
m = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(N, N))

a[...,2][m.astype('bool')] = 42
a
```

Output (for a random example of *a*)

```
array([[[ 9, 13,  4],
        [15,  0, 42],
        [11, 12,  9],
        [13,  0, 42]],

       [[ 1, 10, 42],
        [ 9,  0, 42],
        [ 8,  6,  4],
        [ 3,  0, 42]],

       [[15, 11,  6],
        [ 8, 11, 42],
        [14,  1, 42],
        [ 4, 14,  1]],

       [[ 3,  6, 42],
        [ 5, 13,  3],
        [ 9, 14, 13],
        [12,  6, 42]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me.

```
a[:,:,2] *= (1-m)
a[:,:,2] += m*42
```

Comment: Isn't this a slice at :,:,2? I think we need to still loop over 3rd dimension. Edit: Oh, the d1[2] was hard-coded in the question.

Comment: When I subtract my solution from OP's, I get a zero-filled array; so no. I just modify the last slice without changing the other dims.

Comment: Nope. Compare results with code given. You are zeroing or incrementing elements instead of setting them. See : `a[...,2][m == 1] = 42`

Comment: [My solution?](https://tio.run/##jY9NboMwEIX3PsXbxU4dBKTqAslXyAVQFiYY1VH8I0MX5PJkSFsKqipVsmyP3/eeZ@I4vAd/nCbrYkgD/IeLI3QPHxk7QeGVadp9zJL2bXDPw/qB5xLFm0Rv70bxkwStoxCsIVhnlxBHLpj7y1mujeRiMc3KTsP21U58lfr78gO4DeBWQBcSrESbw3oYGsMkPRjKqBgwi1cSi63Y5k8VsB1cTe7r@bMGoXV5nscv/9FcU1eyksTvFXhxoLaWlxcFt1@FNJuQ5veEre06k4y/mO13h4XlWqlGZPp242LxT9MD) I am first zeroing the elements to be set, after which I add 42. Admittedly, this is not strictly setting them, but it gets 42 in the positions OP required.

Comment: You are completely right. For some reason, I thought that you are offering two different solutions, one per line of code. My apologies, it's late here...

Comment: No probs my man; late night coding is dangerous. Sleep tight, don't let the (bed) bugs bite!